# how to logout fix session?

Tags: quickfix, quickfixj

I'm using quickfixj. I have a custom message like "EndTrade", when I got that message, I want to end fix session? How can I do that?  I have not find any way to do so. 
It is not allowing me to use `new Session().logout()`.

Comment: what is wrong with the done for day message?

Comment: how can I end session?

Comment: Disconnecting or sending a logout message will terminate the session

Comment: Muneeb, this is a very unusual thing to do with FIX.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I got answer of my question. you can logout your fix session in following way.

```
Session.lookupSession(sessionID).logout();
```